# Accepting File Argument in Python (from Send To context menu)

Tags: python, urllib2, contextmenu, sendto

I'm going to start of by noting that I have next to no python experience.

[alt text http://www.aquate.us/u/9986423875612301299.jpg](http://www.aquate.us/u/9986423875612301299.jpg)

As you may know, by simply dropping a shortcut in the Send To folder on your Windows PC, you can allow a program to take a file as an argument.

How would I write a python program that takes this file as an argument?

And, as a bonus if anyone gets a chance -- 
How would I integrate that with a urllib2 to POST the file to a PHP script on my server?

Thanks in advance.

Edit-- also, how do I make something show up in the Sendto menu? I was under the impression that you just drop a shortcut into the SendTo folder and it automatically adds an option in the menu...
Never mind. I figured out what I was doing wrong :)

Comment: If you figured something out then you should add that solution as a edit below your question so that it will help others who stumble on your question as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Find out what the dragged file was: http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.argv
2. Open it: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open
3. Read it in: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.read
4. Post it: http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much for the links. This'll be a breeze now :)

Answer (score 2):

```
import sys

for arg in sys.argv:
  print arg
```